# form value on a vector field

Tags: differential-forms

Let $w=2xy^3zdx+3x^2y^2zdy+xy^2dz$. Calculate the form value on a vector field $v=z\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}$.
I have a problem with it, can someone explain how to do it?

Comment: Hint: What are $dx(\partial/\partial x)$, $dx(\partial/\partial y)$, $dx(\partial/\partial z)$, etc.?

Comment: @TedShifrin $dx(\partial/\partial x)=1, dx(\partial/\partial y=0), dx(\partial/\partial z)=0$. I'm solved it

Comment: There you go! Great!